# Появление объекта при соблюдении условия

Tags: php, html

Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать функцию на PHP + html которая бы выводила на экран картинку при соблюдении условия. В html файле есть статическая картинка например: `<img src="images/img1.jpg" />` и по умолчанию она выводится всегда, а мне нужно чтоб картинка выводилась если в БД будет стоять параметр для картинки например: visible="1"

Comment: Как вариант изначально сделать стиль для картинки `display:none`, а когда приходит ответ от сервера, смотреть `if(visible == 1){$("#id_img").css('display':'block')}` . Соответственно, нужно дополнительно указать `id` для картинки

Comment: Спасибо! Ваш ответ, мне помог! :)

Answer (score 0):

Если на PHP, то можно например так:

```
<?php
if($visible==1)
{ 
?>
    <img src="images/img1.jpg" />
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Не работет, я меняю в таблице 1 на 0 результата нет. $visible = mysql_query("SELECT visible FROM test_db WHERE tovarid='$id'",$link);
if($visible==1)
{
    echo '
<img src="/images/sale.png" />
';
}

Comment: Можно и так. Только использование `echo` на странице не желательно. А, ходить со страницы в БД (только без обид) вообще лютый треш.

Comment: Да согласен :)))))) но я учусь. Но эта моя писанина не работает :((((((

Comment: Лучше сразу учитесь делать как надо.

Comment: Как можно вывести `img` в шаблоне я вам показал. Работу с БД лучше вынести в отдельные класс и получать данные через него.

Comment: спасибо :) буду пробовать

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте этот вариант:

```
<?
/*Этот код нужно выполнять только один раз*/
    $host = 'localhost'; // адрес сервера
    $database = 'your_db'; // имя базы данных
    $user = 'root'; // имя пользователя
    $password = 'your_pass'; // пароль
    // подключаемся к БД
    $link = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $database) or die("Ошибка " . mysqli_error($link));
/*Этот код нужно выполнять только один раз*/


//Делаем запрос в БД
$result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT visible FROM test_db WHERE tovarid=" . $id) or die("Ошибка " . mysqli_error($link));
//В $result->num_rows будет количество строк, если 0 - значит запрос вернул нулевой результат
if($result->num_rows > 0){
    ?>
        <img src="/images/sale.png" />
    <?
}
?>
```

Я так подозреваю вы коннект к DB не сделали или упустили какой-то момент. Только в начале заполните переменные `$host`, `$database`, `$user`, `$password`

Comment: Соединение с БД выведено в отдельный файл.

Comment: Что я не так делаю? В ручном режиме (при подставлении значения $row вручную все работает а из БД не работает)  `$row = 1;
if($row > 0)
{
    echo '
        <img src="/images/Logotype.png" />
    ';
}`

Comment: Вот этот код не работает, картинка постоянно на экране. Значения из БД выводятся. `$result = mysql_query("SELECT sale FROM teplo_db",$link);
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)
{
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
if($row > 0)
{
    echo '
    <img src="/images/Logotype.png" />
    ';
}
}`

Comment: Ваш совет я так понял для PHP старше версии 5,6***. Но я синтаксис подправил и все равно не могу получить работающий результат :(

Comment: На 5.6 так же это должно работать, а на какой версии вы тестируете?

Comment: Сейчас включена версия 5.6

Comment: Вся проблема в том, что при ручном подставлении значения $row и обновлении страницы все работает (картинка исчезает или появляется) а при выводе значения 0 или 1 из БД не работает, картинка постоянно есть

Answer (score 0):

Вот готовое решение, проблема была как всегда в невнимательности, а именно ; после первого if. На это решение навел @radar4ick за что ему огромное спасибо!!!

```
<?php
  $style = 'display:none;';
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT `visible` FROM `test`",$link);
  if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) 
  $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
  if ($row["visible"] > 0)
  {
    $style = 'display:block;';
  }
  echo '
  <img id="id_img" src="/images/Logotype.png" style="'.$style.'" />
  ';
  ?>
```